# Combining multiple columns with missing variables

Tags: r

I am trying to combine multiple columns that will have missing variables. I am very new to R and am having a lot of trouble doing this. For example, I am trying to turn this:

```
ID A     B      A      D
1  fill  NA     NA    Market
2  NA    Ball   fill  NA
3  NA    NA     NA    Market
4  fill  Ball   NA    NA
```

Into this:

```
ID A     B     D
1  fill  NA    Market
2  fill  Ball  NA
3  NA    NA    Market
4  fill  Ball  NA
```

I am having trouble because the database has ~1500 of columns, with many duplicated column names. I tried using melt and groupby, but I could not get it to work. Wherever the column is duplicated, and if it has a value, the column with the same name will not have a value, if that makes sense. I dont know how to get the functions to work without going through the database and identifying the 50 or so duplicated columns (as in 25 columns have a duplicate). There might also be some columns that have triplets, as in three columns of A, but never any overlapping values.

Comment: I think that in R, your columns can't present the same name, so maybe you have `A` and `A.1` or something like that, isn't it?

Comment: No, they have the same name because these columns are created from the spread function acting on multiple variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
# your data
d <- read.table(text="ID A     B      A      D
1  fill  NA     NA    Market
           2  NA    Ball   fill  NA
           3  NA    NA     NA    Market
           4  fill  Ball   NA    NA", header=T)
d
ID    A    B  A.1      D
1  1 fill <NA> <NA> Market
2  2 <NA> Ball fill   <NA>
  3  3 <NA> <NA> <NA> Market
4  4 fill Ball <NA>   <NA>
```

As you can see duplicated colnames are tagged with `.n`
In the follwing we will mutate the names so that they are again duplicated using stringi, then spreading using tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)
d %>% 
  gather(key, value, -ID) %>% 
  mutate(key2=stri_extract_first_words(key)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>% 
  select(ID, key2,  value) %>% 
  spread(key2, value)
  ID    A    B      D
1  1 fill <NA> Market
2  2 fill Ball   <NA>
3  3 <NA> <NA> Market
4  4 fill Ball   <NA>
```

Comment: So if I am understanding this correctly, and correct me if I am wrong because I am very new to R, I would have to have new instances of this for each duplicated column? Is there a way to automate this so it automatically detects which columns are duplicated? I might be wrong about my understanding.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Please revise your question and include some data illustrating the problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `split.default` of base R to split data.frame based on similar column names and merge the data for each subgroup. You may have to do additional step to get the column order right if that is important

```
data.frame(lapply(split.default(df, names(df)),
                  function(x) x[cbind(1:NROW(x), max.col(!is.na(x)))]))
#     A    B      D ID
#1 fill <NA> Market  1
#2 fill Ball   <NA>  2
#3 <NA> <NA> Market  3
#4 fill Ball   <NA>  4
```

**DATA**

```
df = structure(list(ID = 1:4, A = structure(c(1L, NA, NA, 1L), .Label = "fill", class = "factor"), 
    B = structure(c(NA, 1L, NA, 1L), .Label = "Ball", class = "factor"), 
    A = structure(c(NA, 1L, NA, NA), .Label = "fill", class = "factor"), 
    D = structure(c(1L, NA, 1L, NA), .Label = "Market", class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
"A", "B", "A", "D"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```